Setting website link preview using react and mdx (each page of the website a separate image)
I have a website for example "example.com", and the main layout.jsx has below metadata.
export const metadata = {
  title: {
    template: '%s - example',
    default: 'example - exampledescriptionwebsite',
  },
  openGraph: {
    title: 'example',
    description: 'exampledescriptionwebsite',
    url: 'https://example.com/',
    type: 'website',
    images: [
      {
        url: 'https://example.com/previewimages.png',
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        alt: 'Preview image of example.com',
      },
    ],
  },
};


I have a blog section, file directory as below:
src
L public
  L images
    L previewimages.png
Lapp
 L Blog
   L page.jsx
   L wrapper.jsx 
   L BlogTitle
     L page.mdx
L layout.jsx

so I am trying to get example.com/BlogTitle to have a different title, description and image showing when I copy the link and paste it into facebook/telegram/etc, and currently its only showing according to the app/layout.jsx page.
When I add a layout.jsx to the blog folder, I am unable to make it dynamic as the page will load all the blog basic details (like a blog list page), and include link to the wrapper.jsx, which is the actual specific blog page, which will be populated according to the blog details in the BlogTitle page.mdx file.
so it will set the link thumbnail to the blog list page and not the individual blog.
I have set all the metadata inside the BlogTitle/page.mdx file and the page,jsx file just to test, but all the metadata information is just not read or not implemented as the website renders.
pushed to github & hosted on vercel

how do I make the src/app/layout.jsx accept title and description,
image dynamically? that seems to be the only solution to me, please
correct me if im wrong


so I just made the metadata parameters to accept data from the params in the layout.jsx file. I made sure that the parameters are gotten from the page.mdx file itself like below & it works... Cant believe I was stuck here for so long. just leaving the code here so that it helps anyone like me because I havent seen a reply in stackOverflow that helped me
(inside mdx.js)
export async function getArticleBySlug(slug, type) {
  const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), `src/app/${type}/${slug}/page.mdx`);

  if (!fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
    return null; // Return null if the file does not exist
  }

  const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
  const { data, content } = matter(fileContent);

  return {
    metadata: data, // Frontmatter metadata
    content: await serialize(content), // Serialized MDX content
  };
}

(inside layout.jsx)
export async function generateMetadata({ params }) {
  // Dynamically load content based on the route
  const { slug } = params;
  let pageMetadata = {
    title: 'page title',
    description: 'page description',
    url: 'https://page/',
    image: 'https://page/defaultimage.png',
  };

  if (slug) {
    // Example for blog articles
    const articles = await loadArticles();
    const article = articles.find((a) => a.slug === slug);

    if (article) {
      pageMetadata = {
        title: `${article.title} - page`,
        description: article.description || pageMetadata.description,
        url: `https://page/${slug}`,
        image: article.image || pageMetadata.image,
      };
    }
  }

  return {
    title: {
      template: '%s - page',
      default: 'page description',
    },
    openGraph: {
      title: pageMetadata.title,
      description: pageMetadata.description,
      url: pageMetadata.url,
      type: 'website',
      images: [
        {
          url: pageMetadata.image,
          width: 800,
          height: 600,
          alt: 'image',
        },
      ],
    },
  };
}

